# Rails: ActiveRecord: How to extract records with associations and render as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have three models.

- Accommodation
- AccommodationType
- Location

> `AccommodationType` has many `Accommodations`.
>
> `Location` has many `Accommodations`.
>
> `Accommodation` belongs to `Accommodation` and `Location`.

I want to render `Accommodations` together with `AccommodationType` and `Location` as part of json.

What I have tried are -

1st

```
return_obj = {}
return_obj[:error] = false

accommodations = Accommodation.all.includes(:location, :accommodation_type)
return_obj[:accommodations] = accommodations

render :json => return_obj and return
# it does not include location and accommodation_type in json
```

2nd

```
return_obj = {}
return_obj[:error] = false

accommodations = Accommodation.includes(:location, :accommodation_type).all
return_obj[:accommodations] = accommodations

render :json => return_obj and return
# same results as above
```

I know I can get it with

```
accommodations = Accommodation.all
render :json => accommodations.to_json(:include => [:location, :accommodation_type]) and return
```

But, I need to make `accommodations` part of `return_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
render :json => Accommodation.all.to_json(:include => [:location, :accommodation_type]) }
```

Comment: Yeah. I know it works. I want to put accommodations into return_obj and render return_obj as json. Please see at the end of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but, am not sure it is the best.

```
return_obj = {}
return_obj[:error] = false
accommodations = Accommodation.all
return_obj[:accommodations] = JSON.parse(accommodations.to_json(:include => [:location, :accommodation_type]))
render :json => return_obj and return
```

Please let me know if you have better solution giving same result.

Thanks.